# Override actions in ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

ActiveAdmin allows for the **actions** method, which adds view, edit and delete to the index view.

I am overriding this on each index view with something like this:

```rb
  actions defaults: false do |word|
      item "View", admin_word_path(word), class: 'edit_link member_link'
  end
```

This works fine, but I'd like to just have a global override for all index views which doesn't require me writing this code for each.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A way is to dynamically open up the `IndexTableFor` class within `module ActiveAdmin`. Risky, because this might eventually break with ActiveAdmin upgrades. paste the following snippet at the end of your `config/initializers/active_admin.rb` file. I tested this with activeadmin 1.1, rails 5.1 and ruby 2.4.2 and it works.

```
module ActiveAdmin
  module Views
    class IndexAsTable < ActiveAdmin::Component
      class IndexTableFor < ::ActiveAdmin::Views::TableFor
        def defaults(resource, options = {})
          if controller.action_methods.include?('show') && authorized?(ActiveAdmin::Auth::READ, resource)
            item I18n.t('active_admin.view'), resource_path(resource), class: "view_link #{options[:css_class]}", title: I18n.t('active_admin.view')
          end
          if controller.action_methods.include?('edit') && authorized?(ActiveAdmin::Auth::UPDATE, resource)
            item I18n.t('active_admin.edit'), edit_resource_path(resource), class: "edit_link #{options[:css_class]}", title: I18n.t('active_admin.edit')
          end
          if controller.action_methods.include?('destroy') && authorized?(ActiveAdmin::Auth::DESTROY, resource)
            item I18n.t('active_admin.delete'), resource_path(resource), class: "delete_link #{options[:css_class]}", title: I18n.t('active_admin.delete'),
              method: :delete, data: {confirm:    I18n.t('active_admin.delete_confirmation')}
          end
        end
      end
    end
```

You can now tweak this the way you would like. Remember to restart your rails server as it is an `initializer`.

Good luck!